# "'int' object is not iterable" error in python

Tags: python, json

I am getting this error: `'int' object is not iterable` for the following codes which is meant for sending sensor values from my Raspberry Pi to Ubidots. I have read similar questions and answers but I cannot figure out where the error lies.

```
import time
import sys
import traceback
from time import sleep
import requests
import Adafruit_ADS1x15

# Create an ADS1115 ADC (16-bit) instance.
adc = Adafruit_ADS1x15.ADS1115()

GAIN = 1

print('Reading ADS1x15 values, press Ctrl-C to quit...')

while True:
   m = adc.read_adc(0, gain=GAIN)
   try:
    r = requests.post('http://things.ubidots.com/api/v1.6/devices/raspberry/?token={A1E-6l4DwwC86SDR6QRTJWXGDwshTGPHFl}', m)
    print('Moisture Level:{0:>6}'.format(m))
    time.sleep(1)
   except KeyboardInterrupt:
    break
   traceback.print_exc()
```

Traceback:

```
Reading ADS1x15 values, press Ctrl-C to quit...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "soilhumidity2.py", line 23, in <module>
r = requests.post('http://things.ubidots.com/api/v1.6/devices/raspberry/?token={A1E-6l4DwwC86SDR6QRTJWXGDwshTGPHFl}', m)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 110, in post
return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 56, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 443, in send
for i in request.body:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I used this link for reference: http://help.ubidots.com/iot-projects-tutorials/diy-raspberry-pi-temperature-system-with-ubidots

Comment: Your indentation is also off. Correct it please; the `m=...`, the `try` and the `except` have to be at the same level and are in 3 different ones..

Comment: Indentation is still not correct. Copy and paste your code and make sure it runs as expected. (We're not just being pedantic, indentation is very important in Python and can change the nature of errors.)

Comment: Use copy & paste, then select the pasted stuff and press Ctrl-k to indent it rigorously as code.

Comment: Again, this code still throws a syntax error for incorrect indentation. (Much better on the Traceback, though!)

Comment: @glibdud Am sorry, I edited again just now and I posted a link for reference for the Ubidots and Raspberry Pi codes

Comment: I actually realized that the data that I have to parse in to the `requests.post` should be in JSON format which is not the case in my codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method worked for me:

```
import time
import sys
from time import sleep
import requests
import Adafruit_ADS1x15
from ubidots import ApiClient
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

# Create an ApiClient object
api = ApiClient("A1E-0d8bec822d9d5ccae0fb08a75dfdb22e17c3")


# Get a Ubidots Variable
variable = api.get_variable("5a5f80eec03f971388983b8e")


# Create an ADS1115 ADC (16-bit) instance.
adc = Adafruit_ADS1x15.ADS1115()

GAIN = 1

print('Reading ADS1x15 values, press Ctrl-C to quit...')

while True:
    ldr = adc.read_adc(1, gain=GAIN)
    try:
       response = variable.save_value({'value': ldr})
       print response
       print "Light Intensity: %d" % ldr
       time.sleep(0.5)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
       break
    except Exception as e:
       print (e)
```

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation for [`requests.post()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.post):

> Parameters:
>    url -- URL for the new Request object.
>    data -- (optional)
>      **Dictionary (will be form-encoded), bytes, or file-like object** to send
>      in the body of the Request.

It looks like [`read_adc()`](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_ADS1x15/blob/master/Adafruit_ADS1x15/ADS1x15.py#L185) returns an integer, so what you're passing as the `data` parameter is not what `post()` is expecting.

I'm not familiar with Ubidots, so I can't tell you exactly what format it expects the post data in. You'll need to find that out and provide either a `dict` or `bytes` object formatted appropriately.

Edit: Per your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48302110/int-object-is-not-iterable-error-in-python/48302653#comment83589837_48302110), if you need to send JSON data, then prepare the data structure as necessary and send it with:

```
r = requests.post('http://.../', json=m)
```

Comment: I just posted a comment about this.. `requests.post()` expects the data to be parsed in to be in JSON format which I missed out in the codes. I'll add it..

Comment: @MargoRothSpiegelman Updated answer to address that. You still need to create the data structure that the API is expecting, then just pass it to `post()` as the `json` parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I am working on it. Will get back to you when I am done

Comment: Am getting `None` as the JSON result as per the answer below

Comment: Sounds like you've got the Python part worked out and now you may just be having trouble with the API. I unfortunately can't help you with that. Maybe Ubidots has a help forum or something?

Comment: Thanks, will look into that :)

Answer (score 1):

the payload in `request.post` has to be a dictionary :

```
import time
import sys
from time import sleep
import requests
import Adafruit_ADS1x15

# Create an ADS1115 ADC (16-bit) instance.
adc = Adafruit_ADS1x15.ADS1115()

GAIN = 1

print('Reading ADS1x15 values, press Ctrl-C to quit...')

while True:
    m = adc.read_adc(0, gain=GAIN)
    payload={'adc value ': m}
    try:
        r = requests.post('http://things.ubidots.com/api/v1.6/devices/raspberry/?token={A1E-6l4DwwC86SDR6QRTJWXGDwshTGPHFl}', data=payload)
        print('Moisture Level:{0:>6}'.format(m))
        time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
```

cf `payload = {'temp_celsius': temp_c, 'temp_fahrenheit': temp_f}` in http://help.ubidots.com/iot-projects-tutorials/diy-raspberry-pi-temperature-system-with-ubidots

Comment: I am getting `None` as the JSON result on my console

Comment: i am not familiar with ubidots however in the tutorial http://help.ubidots.com/iot-projects-tutorials/diy-raspberry-pi-temperature-system-with-ubidots the data is organized  like this. this is also in https://ubidots.com/docs/api/

Comment: Yeah, I checked that. I'll search on Ubidots forums for more help. Thanks a lot